# Call external function from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, call, external

I admit that I'm new to AngularJS and still don't know it well.
However, my problem is that I need to call a function in an external .js file from a controller.

This is my code:

```
menuapp.controller("barcodeController", function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {

$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        var code = 36;//imageData.text.split('=')[1];
        if(code) {
            //external function
        }
        console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
        console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
};
});
```

I'm using this to scan a barcode, extract what's after the "=" and send it to an external function. However I can't simply call those function and I can't figure a simple way to do that.

Any help?

Comment: Please show the external function you're trying to call?

Comment: *Why* can't you simply call the function?

Comment: @isherwood it's not getting called at all. I thought that this was normal, isn't it?

Comment: @tcooc sure, i'm editing the post

Comment: It would be more useful to see where the external is defined, rather than what it does. what it does is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Have you tried `openrestaurant(code)`? Add an `window.alert(code)` to the beginning of the function to see if it's called. Also check your console for errors.

Comment: I assume it's just globally defined in an external js file, in which case my guess is the function IS being called, it just isn't doing what you expect it to do, which is another problem entirely (and a debugging failure, you should have added a breakpoint in the function to confirm that it isn't being called.)

Comment: @KevinB it's just there. This code is written, as it is, in a file that's totally external to Angular

Comment: We need to know more about your setup. Is this external file included in the HTML page at all?

Comment: it's not obvious what happens when you try to call this function;  Do you get an error, or does it do something other than what you expect?  There is no reason that you can't call this function from your existing code (it is all JavaScript, after all), unless the script just isn't loaded in your HTML page at all.  That being said, this function appears to be doing something in JQuery, to change the DOM, which is normally not necessary with angular, but probably should be isolated to a directive when it is.

Comment: if function is in global namespace should be able to call it, otherwise you have a scope problem. What happens when it's called...errors? Better to rewrite it anyway into angular paradigm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference the external Javascript file from your html, you will have access to the function from within your controller.

Html:

```
<script src="URL"></script>
```

Controller:

```
if(code) {
     openrestaurant(code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a global instance of the function.

Add a line:

```
var abc= new funcName();
```

at the end of the File and you can use this line (var abc= new funcName();) in your controller to
invoke any methods from this file by using abc.methodName.